# OpenShift Jenkins find out current namespace in pipeline

Tags: jenkins

We have a Jenkins deployed in OpenShift and we run our workers also in OpenShift. My question is: is there a way to find out the current namespace where Jenkins is running?

Our public is that we have many namespaces for different projects and in each of those namespaces  a separate instance of Jenkins is running. We need to know the namespace where the Jenkins is running to load some project dependent values and settings.

A simple `oc project` yields just "Not currently on any project".